# How can I debug an Azure Cosmos DB stored procedure?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Resulting message would be too large because of \\\"Body\\\". Return from script with current message and use continuation token to call the script again or modify your script.
```

When I run:

```
DocumentClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<object>(...)
```

I've tried reproducing the stored proc call in the Azure Portal, but when I run it, it never finishes.

I've left it like this for a few mins and no results are returned.

I can't see any network tab errors in the F12 Dev Tools:
[image]

Here's the stored proc code:

```
    function (contacts, companyReference, propertyReference) {
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var response = context.getResponse();
    var messageThreads = [];
    if (!contacts) throw new Error("contacts cannot be null");
    if (contacts.length == 0) {
        response.setBody(JSON.stringify(messageThreads));
    }
    var contactsLength = contacts.length - 1;
    var count = 0;
    GetContactMessages(contacts[count], callback);
    function GetContactMessages(cnt, callback) {
        var qry = 'SELECT r.Subject, r.Message, r.Participants, r.FromAddress, r.ToAddress, r.ThreadID, r.Sent, r.AttachmentUrls, r.id FROM root r WHERE r.DocType = 1 AND r.ToAddress.CompanyReference = "' + companyReference + '" AND r.ToAddress.ContactReference = "' + cnt.Item1 + '" AND r.ToAddress.ContactReferenceType = ' + cnt.Item2;
        if (cnt.ContactReferenceType === 3) {
            //owner contact type. return messages which are either about the owner or about a specific property.
            qry = qry + ' AND (r.EntityType = 0 OR (r.EntityType = 2 AND r.EntityReference = "' + propertyReference + '"))';
        }
        var accept = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), qry, { pageSize: 1000 }, callback);
        if (!accept) throw "Unable to read messages, abort ";
    }
    function MessageExists(messages, messageId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            if (messages[i].MessageID == messageId) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    function callback(err, documents, responseOptions) {
        if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);
        var messages = documents;
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            var message = messages[i];
            var threadFound = false;
            var alreadyMatched = false;
            var matched = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < messageThreads.length; j++) {
                if (messageThreads[j].ThreadID == message.ThreadID) {
                    var thread = messageThreads[j];
                    if (message.Sent < thread.ThreadStartDate) {
                        thread.ThreadStartDate = message.Sent;
                    }
                    if (!MessageExists(thread.Messages, message.id)) {
                        thread.Messages.push({ MessageID: message.id, MessageDate: message.Sent, Sender: message.FromAddress.DisplayName, Message: message.Message, AttachmentUrls: message.AttachmentUrls });
                    }
                    threadFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!threadFound) {
                messageThreads.push({
                    Subject: message.Subject,
                    ThreadID: message.ThreadID,
                    Participants: message.Participants,
                    ThreadStartDate: message.Sent,
                    Messages: [{ MessageID: message.id, MessageDate: message.Sent, Sender: message.FromAddress.DisplayName, Message: message.Message, AttachmentUrls: message.AttachmentUrls }]
                });
            }
        }
        count++;
        if (count > contactsLength) {
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(messageThreads));
        }
        else {
            GetContactMessages(contacts[count], callback);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the inputs:

Partition key value = `e8fd4796-ee13-4fb1-9417-23f1fb6c86af`

contacts = `[{ContactReferenceType:3, ContactReference:"872730"}, {ContactReferenceType:4, ContactReference:"872734"}]`

companyReference = `e8fd4796-ee13-4fb1-9417-23f1fb6c86af`

propertyReference = `229113`

How can I debug the stored proc to see where it's getting stuck?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code of your stored procedure instead of the screenshot.

Comment: I would advise not using stored procedures at all. Stored procedures are really only useful when frequently bulk inserting well over 100 documents. Anything 100 or fewer I recommend using transactional batch in the .NET or Java SDKs.  Stored procedures for queries (especially with high concurrency) will have sub-optimal performance because they only operate on the primary replica. This means it only gets 1/4 of the throughput provisioned.  They're also extremely difficult to debug as you've discovered.  I would do what you're doing here using a regular query with the SDK.

Comment: I realised the JSON was not correct. I needed double quotes around the property names. I also just found out you can use console.log() and view the logs in the Azure Poral under "console.log" next to the "Result" tab. However the sproc is still hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tab called console.log next to Result in the Azure Portal under the Javascript code.

This displayed any logs from `console.log()`.

With trial and error I found that 1259 was the max the for loop would work with before I got the error.

The `Body` param in the exception message I think is from this line near the bottom of my code:

```
response.setBody(JSON.stringify(messageThreads));
```

The param name for `setBody` is probably `Body`.